# How to secure backand (back&) on demand action

Tags: backand

How can I return a 403 in the on demand actions of backand if the user is not allowed  to execute the action?

Comment: check your back& app "Security&auth-->Configuration-->AnonymouseAccess" if it is false then only authenticated users can call your API set, a non authenticated user will receive a 401 "Message": "invalid or expired token"

Comment: But how can I restrict to special user groups?

Answer (score 0):

Back& security is based on [Roles](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/security/#role-based-security), Back& security templates lets you decide which role(Admin, user, ReadOnly....) can do what(Create Read Update and Delete) and to which object. Because the action is a "child" of an object then any modification you are doing to the object security effects the access to its actions.